# Asynchronous UIKit State Restoration

Tags: ios, uikit

My application uses Core Data, and as a result has the potential for occasional long launch times resulting from migrations. To try to improve the experience when this happens, migrations are performed asynchronously and my app launches a loading view controller.

The problem I'm having is that, when using state restoration, iOS wants to go restoring application state just after `application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is called, but this may be too early to start as I may not have finished setting up the data store yet. There doesn't appear to be any API to asynchronously notify iOS when the application is actually ready to begin reassembling.

As a result, I'm seeing two options:

1. Force migrations to happen synchronously on the main thread in willFinishLaunchingWithOptions, before state restoration
2. Make every core data method in my application return a promise and execute in the background - then they can all be chained off a base promise that is fulfilled when the app finishes launching

Both of these options feel fairly poor. One significantly hinders user experience, the other forces a large chunk of the codebase to adapt to a single (application launch time) concern. Is there another strategy to this, or UIKit supported approach?

**Edit**

In case it's not clear, the connection between the two is that I want to preserve (via state restoration) view controllers that are showing data from core data, such that when they are restored, that data is pulled back out of core data and rendered.